# How to execute Spark job remotely on a machine without Spark installed?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have spark, hadoop, cassandra installed on a remote PC, whoses address is `10.211.55.3`, whose name is `ubuntu`. (in fact, it's a Virtual Machine on my mac). For the local PC, I don't have Spark installed, I have only Java(and of course all the necessary jar files).

Now, it is possible to launch a master and several slaves on the remote PC, and `spark-shell` works fine on the remote PC as well.

I have created a Java project on the local PC, in which I would like to connect to the master on the remote PC in order to post Spark jobs, but the connection fails, no matter if I use

```
new SparkConf().setAppName("TestApp").setMaster("spark://10.211.55.3:7077");
```

or

```
new SparkConf().setAppName("TestApp").setMaster("spark://ubuntu:7077");
```

I believe that I should use the version with the IP address, but it gives me these error messages:

```
Could not connect to 10.211.55.3:7077: akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@10.211.55.3:7077]
akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://sparkMaster@10.211.55.3:7077/), Path(/user/Master)]
```

So my question is, is it possible to execute a Java application with a Spark job on the local PC (where Spark is not installed, there is only the jar files) ?
If possible, is there some options/parameters to enable this? Or it is absolutely necessary to install Spark on the local PC?

Thanks a lot !

**Edit 1**:
OK. I confess what I'm doing...I have a Mac and I've installed a Ubuntu virtual machine in it. The IP address of the virtual machine is `10.211.55.3`.

Besides, the master/slaves are running, I can access their state via the web browser, the ip address works as well.

Comment: are you able to browe http://master-ip:8080 and see the spark cluster running ?

Comment: Did you try pinging this address to make sure it works ?

Comment: You do know that 10.211.55.3 is a subnetwork created by the virtualization software you are using and you can't access it from the Local PC.

Comment: Set the virtual machine network adapter to bridged mode before trying to connect to it from an external host (e.g not your mac).

Comment: @Teodor-BogdanBarbieru Thanks your your advice, but it still doesn't work even if I change the network adapter to bridged mode.

Comment: Right, but then you need to connect to the new bridged network IP.